# Multi-dimensional array from mysql to json

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-push

I am trying to get the following json:

```
{
"1": {
    "A1": {
        "drink": "Beer",
        "volume": "0.0965"
    },
    "A2": {
        "drink": "Beer",
        "volume": "0.1029"
    }
}, // etc.
```

My php is:

```
$sql = "SELECT keg_no, sub_no, drink, volume FROM keg ORDER BY keg_no, sub_no, drink, volume;";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rows = array();
foreach ($results as $row)
    $rows[$row['keg_no']][$row['sub_no']] [] = [drink=>$row['drink'], volume=>$row['volume']];
$json = json_encode($rows);
echo $json;
```

My javascript is:

```
    function getKegs () {
    $.post('getKegs.php', {}, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            keg = $.parseJSON(data);
        } else
           alert('No reply from database');
    });
}
```

The above results in an unwanted dimension in square brackets:

```
{
"1": {
    "A1": [{
        "drink": "Beer",
        "volume": "0.0965"
    }],
    "A2": [{
        "drink": "Beer",
        "volume": "0.1029"
    }], // etc.
```

The square brackets can be removed using str_replace(php)/replace(js) and I still get valid json without the unnecessary dimension but it will be much more satisfactory to understand why/how the square brackets are added and how they can be removed.

Comment: also play with `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flags or just type cast into an object

Comment: JSON_FORCE_OBJECT keeps the extra dimension... I will look into type casting but since I have it working with replace I am just curious if it can be easily made to work as desired..

Comment: `$rows[$row['keg_no']][$row['sub_no']] [] = [drink=>$row['drink'], volume=>$row['volume']];` to `$rows[$row['keg_no']][$row['sub_no']] = [drink=>$row['drink'], volume=>$row['volume']];` ?

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot. How do I mark a comment as answer?